# NSPopupbutton combining two values for Content. Perhaps similar to DisplayPattern

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, nsmanagedobject, nspopupbutton

Id like to use a `NSPopupbutton` to show a list. each element in the list combine **two** attributes from an `NSManagedObject`.

```
"firstname, userid"
```

I'd rather not add a transient attribute, since that dirties the business logic.

Is there a simple method of merging two values for the Content Values in the `NSPopupbutton`

It looks like NSLabel has a DisplayPattern. Nevertheless, that also appears to permit only binding to one attribute, although it might accommodate the string formatting.

OSX not iOS.

Comment: why not to use a property and bind that to NSpopup. And that property will use nsstring appendWithFormat from your managedobject? You can also use valueTransformer class

Comment: i was hoping to avoid introducing business logic or state -- given thats its UI appearance. `nsvaluetransformer` looks possible. is that an object that can be placed into a nib and bound via IB.

Comment: is see that nspopup (and nslabel) has a value transformer option. are you familiar with the best sample code.

Comment: it looks like the 'Temperature Converter' sample is the best example. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Once common way to do this while keeping the view code separate from the model code is to use Objective-C categories.  If your managed object subclass were named `MyManagedObject`, you would do something like this:

```
@interface MyManagedObject (ViewSupport)

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString* stringForPopUpButton;

@end


@implementation MyManagedObject (ViewSupport)

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingStringForPopUpButton
{
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"firstname", @"userid", nil];
}

- (NSString *)stringForPopUpButton
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@, %@", self.firstname, self.userid];
}

@end
```

This code can appear in a separate file, or whatever.  This pattern works well for simple things like combining two properties.  For more complex transformations, the logic will usually live in an `NSViewController` subclass.  The model is typically pushed into these objects using the `-representedObject` property and then the accompanying views can be constructed in Xcode/InterfaceBuilder, etc.  This pattern keeps the data munging logic coupled with the view/nib/xib that uses it.

Comment: I've done something similar in the past. Having a property in a Category. Categories are awesome (tm). But skipped over the keyPathsForValuesAffectingXXX procedure. Is that something to do with KVO. cheers

Comment: Yes, it's for KVO. See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html

Comment: Hayzeus. Thats what im seeking. So is that how transient properties are often updated -- should they rely on other props. For example the 'fullname' in that document could be a transient property on a managedobject....

Comment: further im guessing that is convenience for adding an observer in awakeFromInsert and doing the whole observeValueForKeyPath yaddayadda

Comment: morese, im hoping one can do something along the lines of return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"employees.firstname", @"employees.userid", nil]; although that clearly would be a performance drain